# How to import new module to custom layer in QGroundControl

Tags: qt, qml, qgroundcontrol

I'm working on a custom build of QGroundcontrol;
I've tried to import an existing module (QtQuick.shapes 1.12) to CustomFlyViewVideo.qml. The code builds normally, but when I try to run it I get these errors:

```
qrc:/qml/MainRootWindow.qml:469 Type FlyView unavailable

qrc:/qml/QGroundControl/FlightDisplay/FlyView.qml:147 Type FlyViewVideo unavailable

qrc:/qml/QGroundControl/FlightDisplay/FlyViewVideo.qml:23 module "QtQuick.Shapes" is not installed
```

Comment: Qt Quick Shapes were added in Qt 5.10. Which Qt version are you using?

Comment: Hey, I'm using 5.12.6
Thanks for answering

Comment: You can run the application with `QML_IMPORT_TRACE` set to `1` and then make sure that you see a directory in the list of import paths from that output that contains a QtQuick/Shapes directory.